# error: expireAfterAccess(long,TimeUnit) is not public in MapMaker; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: guava

I upgrade guava to 18.0 from r09 when I upgrade JDK to 1.8. But there is an error like the title.

And the same accessing restriction for method MapMaker.maximumSize.

Anyone know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[`MapMaker`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html)'s caching functionalities were deprecated and moved to new [`com.google.common.cache`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/package-summary.html#package_description) package ([see migration guide](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/MapMakerMigration)):

> The core interface used to represent caches is `Cache`. In-memory caches can be configured and created using `CacheBuilder`, with cache entries being loaded by `CacheLoader`. Statistics about cache performance are exposed using `CacheStats`.

Right now `MapMaker` acts as kind of `ConcurrentMapBuilder` without any caching capabilities, so you should use [`CacheBuilder`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), ex.:

```
Cache<Integer, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10000)
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
```

Note that you could pass [`CacheLoader`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) to build if you want to compute values. Also, if you need `Map` interface to cache, you can use [`Cache#asMap()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap()) view.

Comment: If so, please [mark answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote :)